# htmlentities returning empty string

Tags: php, html-entities

The following code outputs an empty string. The cause is the "ó" in $text, but why? What characters does utf-8 encode then?

The problem is solved when using iso-8859-1, but I need to use utf-8, so what am I doing wrong?

```
<!doctype html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
</head>

<body>
<?
$text = 'Hola ó Hola';
$text = htmlentities($text,ENT_QUOTES,'utf-8');
echo $text;
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Strange, your code seems to work fine on my computer. (returns `&oacute;`) - the only thing I changed was changing `<?` to `<?php`, you could try that.

Comment: I Think i may be saving my files in the wrong charset ? Is that possible ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Make sure you save your source file as UTf-8 if it contains the string. Else make sure that whatever is supplying the string supplies it as UTF-8.

Comment: What if the source of the text is a $_POST ? Where do i get the char set encoding?

Comment: If the `POST` request comes from a form on the same website which emits a `utf-8` meta-charset you can assume the input charset will be `utf-8` as well (your browser should adhere to whatever charset header is emitted, but it might chose not to at the users discretion). I suppose you could try some PHP functions to see what PHP thinks the charset is; like `iconv_get_encoding` but I've used it with mixed success.

Comment: K thanks. Is there any resource/guide that could help me understand charsets better ? Im just confused with so many charsets: The charset on <meta charset="">, the charset on MySQL collation, the charset on which the file is saved. It messed my head up :P

Comment: It's very simple really. Always use `utf-8` for everything, always. Source files, `MySQL NAMES` the who shebang. But yea, you do have to always specific that you want `utf-8` because for some bizarre reason it's not the default.

Comment: The problem is, as far as i can tell, i AM using utf-8 for everything, but something's not getting encoded ! How can i contact u personally so i can explain my error please ? :)

Comment: Also, WHICH of all utf's encoding do i put in mysql collation ? Im using utf8_bin, but there are lots of them

Comment: Dont mean to spam, but i think i may be near solving it by defining header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8'); on top of the code, its weird, because i thought i was defining the charset header with  this line <meta charset="utf-8">

Comment: `utf8_general_ci` is the one you want. `utf8_bin` is really for binary data and some MySQL function may behave differently because of it. `ci` just stands for case-insensitive as MySQL is case-insensitive by default (or apparently by default collation)

Comment: Yes I know, it's all very redundant, but also necessary.

Comment: Frits van Campen: Thank you **SO** much. Seriously.

Answer (score 39):

I had a similar issue and used the flag ENT_SUBSTITUTE to prevent the empty string.  It still didn't encode, and I couldn't rely on the file being UTF-8, so I converted the encoding on just the string:

```
$text = htmlentities(mb_convert_encoding($text, 'UTF-8', 'ASCII'), ENT_SUBSTITUTE, "UTF-8");
```

Comment: This is the option that worked for me as far as the string not being blank, but it is not showing the special characters, those are just omitted from the string. Any ideas on how to get the special characters to show? In my case, it is a bullet, read in from an old db.

Comment: `$text = htmlentities(utf8_encode($text));` also works.

Answer (score 0):

1. Open your code editor (notepad++ for instance or other).
2. Click in `New > Save As..` put the name of file (blank for a while) and in type select `PHP Hypertext ...`
3. Now copy all content of your original file and put in this new file.
4. Click in **save** and try.

Answer (score 0):

Just commenting for others who may have a similar problem as myself. $var containing special characters. This …

```
<?= htmlentities($var) ?>
```

… gave me an empty output, while …

```
<?php echo htmlentities($var); ?>
```

… worked fine. Same with htmlspecialchars. Never encountered this before because I normally don't use it that way but here I was just testing something out.